# Create an array of functions using array index in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I create an array of multiple functions that I can use like `b[2]()` so I do not need to hardcode the return value but just use the array index instead for `const a`?

```
const a = [...Array(100)]
const b= [()=>{return 0}, ()=>{return 1}, ()=>{return 2},()=>{return 3}]
expect(b[2]()).equal(2)
```

Comment: I think I interpreted your question correctly. But why would you want this? You would need to know the index in order to get the value, and the value would be the index you already know.

Comment: because in my case my array is about 1000 element object that I want to create a function of array to only return the value from specify key of object in that array based on index

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.from` method and for each element return another function that will return index.

```js
const f = Array.from(Array(100), (_, i) => () => i)

console.log(f[2]())
console.log(f[99]())
```

If you already have an array of elements then you can use `map`

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'bar']
const f = arr.map(e => (a) => `${a} ${e}`)

console.log(f[0]('Value:'))
```